# Fuzzy Match based on Key Words

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have two tables

```
df_1
```

[image]

```
df_2
```

[image]

Is there any way I could develop a fuzzy match logic (either in Python or in R) to find `ID` from `df_2` for `df_1`?

The match should be based on fuzzy `name` match, accurate `city`, `state` and `zip` match.
If I couldn't find a match in `city_1`, I would look for match in `city_2`. If I couldn't find a match in `state_1`, I would look for a match in `state_2`. The same thing for `df_2`. If I couldn't find a fuzzy name match in `NAME_1`, I would go to find a fuzzy match at `NAME_2`.

The expected output should be like below:
[image: df_3]

Comment: checkout fuzzywuzzy library. And don't forget to install python-Levenshtein

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [fuzzywuzzy](http://pip%20install%20fuzzywuzzy) library. It uses Lavenstein distance to compare matches. If you are not convinced by the results, you can use  [n gram analysis](http://pip%20install%20ngram).